# Error "snapshot.val" is not a function in Google Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

When creating a new node, I want to create and push that same data into a different node.

The "ins" node is the node I am pushing the new data into:

```
root: { 
  doors: {
    111111111111: {
       MACaddress: "111111111111",
       inRoom: "-LBMH_8KHf_N9CvLqhzU",
       ins: {
          // I am creating several "key: pair"s here, something like:
          1525104151100: true,
          1525104151183: true,
       }
    }
  },
  rooms: {
    -LBMH_8KHf_N9CvLqhzU: {
      ins: {
        // I want it to clone the same data here:
        1525104151100: true,
        1525104151183: true,
      }
    }
  }
```

My function code is the following but it's not working at all. I can't even start the function when I use the **onCreate** trigger (which is all I need). Any ideas on how to make this work?

```
exports.updateRoom = functions.database.ref('doors/{MACaddress}/ins')
.onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    const timestamp = snapshot.val();
    const roomPushKey = functions.database.ref('doors/{MACaddress}/inRoom');
    console.log(roomPushKey);  
    return snapshot.ref.parent.parent.child('rooms').child(roomPushKey).child('ins').set(timestamp);
});
```

Note: I have fiddled with the code and I got it to run by changing the trigger to **onWrite** but like this I get an error message:   *"snapshot.val" is not a function*...

```
exports.updateRoom = functions.database.ref('doors/{MACaddress}/ins').onWrite((snapshot, context) => {     
    const timestamp = snapshot.val();
    const roomPushKey = functions.database.ref('doors/{MACaddress}/inRoom');
    console.log(roomPushKey);
    return snapshot.ref.parent.parent.child('rooms').child(roomPushKey).child('ins').set(timestamp);
});
```

Comment: I did. I will mark it as correct but my code is still not working. Could you point me into writing the the function correctly? I will make a new question.

Comment: is it still not working with `onCreate`? I explained below why it does not work with `onWrite`

Comment: yeah... the `onCreate` wasn't running... I have managed to do a little progress with your tips about the `onWrite`. But I would appreciate some help more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50120415/how-do-i-get-to-another-node-right-nodes-in-google-cloud-function-from-within-a

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you are using `onWrite`, you have to do the following:

```
exports.dbWrite = functions.database.ref('/path').onWrite((change, context) => {
 const beforeData = change.before.val(); // data before the write
 const afterData = change.after.val(); // data after the write
});
```

`onWrite` is used when any changes happen in the specified path, so you can retrieve the `before` the changes and `after` the changes.

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#realtime-database

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.Change

In `onCreate`, you can do this:

```
exports.dbCreate = functions.database.ref('/path').onCreate((snap, context) => {
const createdData = snap.val(); // data that was created
});
```

Since `onCreate` is triggered when you add new data to the database.