# How do I get to a specific node in Google Cloud Function from within a `onWrite` function triggered by another node event?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

When creating a new node, I want to create and push that same data into a different node.

The **Door/111111111111/ins** node is the node I am pushing the new data into:

```
root: { 
  doors: {
    111111111111: {
       MACaddress: "111111111111",
       inRoom: "-LBMH_8KHf_N9CvLqhzU",
       ins: {
          // I am creating several "key: pair"s here, something like:
          1525104151100: true,
          1525104151183: true,
       }
    }
  },
  rooms: {
    -LBMH_8KHf_N9CvLqhzU: {
      ins: {
        // I want the function to clone the same data here:
        1525104151100: true,
        1525104151183: true,
      }
    }
  }
```

This is my function which is throwing an error:

> TypeError: change.before.ref.parent.child(...).val is not a function

Code:

```
exports.updateRoom = functions.database.ref('/doors/{MACaddress}/ins').onWrite((change, context) => {
    const beforeData = change.before.val(); // data before the write
    console.log(beforeData); // all good so far
    const afterData = change.after.val(); // data after the write
    console.log(afterData); // all good so far

    const roomPushKey = change.before.ref.parent.child('/inRoom').val(); // ERROR
    console.log(roomPushKey);

    return change.after.ref.parent.parent.parent.child('/rooms').child(roomPushKey).child('/ins').set(afterData);
});
```

What is wrong with my path? How can I get it to update the other node?

Comment: `Error: Reference.child failed: First argument was an invalid path = "undefined". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[child()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#child) is a method on [Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference) that returns another Reference object.  Reference doesn't have a val() method because it doesn't contain any data.  It's just a reference.

To get data outside the location of the database trigger, you need to query Realtime Database for it.  Use the [once()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#once) method for that.  This is extremely common, and you should be able to use samples and documentation to figure out what you need to do.

Comment: Thanks Coding Doug. I was hoping something so common would have a sample or two and I had looked for similar samples. Unfortunately I couldn't find one. Could you point me to one that does this (cloning a node in a different location)? Many thanks.

Comment: Note: I got rid of the ref.....val() error but still I am hitting a wall:


`Error: Reference.child failed: First argument was an invalid path = "https://clipclop020.firebaseio.com/doors/111111111111/inRoom". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"` 

The path looks totally fine to me : /

Comment: That sounds a different issue that requires a different question to explain what you've done.

Comment: Ok. Will create a new question. Thanks.

Comment: here is the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50134226/how-to-clone-a-node-to-another-path-based-on-a-reference-value-from-the-initial