# How to clone a node to another path based on a reference value from the initial path on Google Cloud Functions?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am trying clone an "original" node's data (as soon as I create the data) to a path that is based on the original node's path.

This is my data structure:

```
root: { 
  doors: {
    111111111111: {
       MACaddress: "111111111111",
       inRoom: "-LBMH_8KHf_N9CvLqhzU", // I will need this value for the clone's path
       ins: {
          // I am creating several "key: pair"s here, something like:
          1525104151100: true,
          1525104151183: true,
       }
    }
  },
  rooms: {
    -LBMH_8KHf_N9CvLqhzU: {
      ins: {
        // I want the function to clone the same data here:
        1525104151100: true,
        1525104151183: true,
      }
    }
  }
```

My cloud function is now like this:

```
exports.updateRoom = functions.database.ref('/doors/{MACaddress}/ins').onWrite((change, context) => {
    const beforeData = change.before.val(); // data before the write
    const afterData = change.after.val(); // data after the write
    const roomPushKey = change.before.ref.parent.child('/inRoom');
    console.log(roomPushKey); // this is retrieving all the info about the ref "inRoom" but not its value...
```

Question 1) How can I get to this ref/node's value?

My code goes on by trying to get the value like this.

```
    roomPushKey.once('child_added').then(function(dataSnapshot) {
        let snapVal = dataSnapshot.val();
        console.log(snapVal);
});
```

Question 2 (which I think is basically question 1 rephrased): How can I get the **snapVal** outside the **then.** method's scope?

```
    return change.after.ref.parent.parent.parent.child('/rooms')
.child(snapVal).child('/ins').set(afterData);
      // snapVal should go above
   });
```

> Error message: *ReferenceError: snapVal is not defined*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work.

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
....
....

exports.updateRoom = functions.database.ref('/doors/{MACaddress}').onWrite((change, context) => {
    const afterData = change.after.val(); // data after the write

    const roomPushKey = afterData.inRoom;
    const ins = afterData.ins;

    const updates = {};
    updates['/rooms/' + roomPushKey] = ins;
    return admin.database().ref().update(updates);

}).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
    //+ other rerror treatment if necessary

});
```

Here are some explanations:

You get the roomPushKey by reading the "data after the write" as an object: `roomPushKey = afterData.inRoom`. You don't need to do `roomPushKey.once('child_added').then()`

Once you have the `roomPushKey`, you create a new child node in the `rooms` node by using `update()` and creating an object with square brackets notation which allow you to assign the id of the node (i.e. roomPushKey).

Note that you could also do:

```
return admin.database().ref('/rooms/' + roomPushKey).set(ins);
```

Note also that you have to import `firebase-admin` in order to be able to do return `admin.database().ref()...`

*Finally, I would suggest that you have a look at the three following videos from the Firebase team: [youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA&t=517s](http://youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA&t=517s) & [youtube.com/watch?v=652XeeKNHSk&t=27s](http://youtube.com/watch?v=652XeeKNHSk&t=27s) & [youtube.com/watch?v=d9GrysWH1Lc](http://youtube.com/watch?v=d9GrysWH1Lc). A must for anyone starting coding for Cloud Functions.*

Comment: Hi Renaud! Thanks. I am trying the code you typed above and it's still not doing it. I console.logged all the errors that I am still getting maybe you can make better sense of what is causing them as I am quite lost here:

`Reference.update failed: First argument contains undefined in property 'rooms.undefined' //
updates: [object Object] //
ins: undefined //
roomPushKey: undefined //
afterData: ,true,true `

Comment: @JoaoAlvesMarrucho I see there is an error in the declaration of the database location where the function is "waiting for changes". It should be `exports.updateRoom = functions.database.ref('/doors/{MACaddress}').onWrite()` instead of `exports.updateRoom = functions.database.ref('/doors/{MACaddress}/ins').onWrite()`. In such a way you easily get the `inRoom` data and the `ins` one. I've udated the answer.

Comment: @JoaoAlvesMarrucho Cool :-)

Comment: @JoaoAlvesMarrucho By the way, do you know that you can find on GitHub a lot of samples of Cloud Function written by the Firebase team: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples. It worth having  a look and study the patterns they use for different cases..

Comment: Yes. I had a quick look before. I will go deeper in asap. Many thanks!

Comment: I have another question related to this. Maybe you can help?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50139303/how-to-update-a-node-without-overwriting-all-the-child-nodes

Comment: @JoaoAlvesMarrucho I've added an answer