# How to update a node without overwriting all the child nodes with Google Cloud Function using a update Object?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am updating "Rooms/{pushId}/ins" with a Google Cloud function that gets new *In* data from several "doors/{MACaddress}/ins".
The function currently goes like like this:

```
exports.updateRoomIns = functions.database.ref('/doors/{MACaddress}').onWrite((change, context) => {
    const beforeData = change.before.val(); // data before the write (data of all the doors child nodes)
    const afterData = change.after.val(); // data after the write (data of all the doors child nodes)
    const roomPushKey = afterData.inRoom; // get the right room
    const insbefore = beforeData.ins;
    const insafter = afterData.ins; // get the after data of only the "ins" node
    console.log(insafter);

    if (insbefore != insafter) {
        const updates = {};
```

The line directly above "const updates = {}" creates an empty object to be (later) populated, and to (later) update the "rooms/{roompushkey}/ins" node...

I think the problem may be here, on the "updates" const, as this object is redefined as a whole every time the function runs...

the code proceeds...

```
        updates['/rooms/' + roomPushKey + '/ins'] = insafter; // populate the "INS" object with the values taken from the "/doors/{MACaddress/ins"
        return admin.database().ref().update(updates); // do the update
    } else {
    return
    }
});
```

This would work if I only had one door, but as I have several doors with different Ins data, every time I update a single "Door/{MACaddress/Ins", the whole "Rooms/{pushId}/Ins" gets replaced for whatever data is on the last updated door... I know the **update** method should be used for this purpose, and I kinda want to keep this "updates" object to fan out the data to other paths later. Is this possible? Any suggestions on how to solve this?

This is my data structure:

```
root: { 
  doors: {
    111111111111: {
       MACaddress: "111111111111",
       inRoom: "-LBMH_8KHf_N9CvLqhzU", // I will need this value for the clone's path
       ins: {
          // I am creating several "key: pair"s here, something like:
          1525104151100: true,
          1525104151183: true,
       }
    },
    222222222222: {
       MACaddress: "222222222222",
       inRoom: "-LBMH_8KHf_N9CvLqhzU", // I will need this value for the clone's path
       ins: {
          // I am creating several "key: pair"s here, something like:
          2525104157710: true,
          2525104157711: true,
       }
    }
  },
  rooms: {
    -LBMH_8KHf_N9CvLqhzU: {
      ins: {
        // I want the function to clone the same data here:
        1525104151100: true,
        1525104151183: true,
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elaborating from my previous answer to your related question ([How to clone a node to another path based on a reference value from the initial path on Google Cloud Functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50134226/how-to-clone-a-node-to-another-path-based-on-a-reference-value-from-the-initial)), I would adapt the code as follow:

```
exports.updateRoom = functions.database.ref('/doors/{MACaddress}').onWrite((change, context) => {
    const afterData = change.after.val(); // data after the write

    const roomPushKey = afterData.inRoom;
    const ins = afterData.ins;

    const updates = {};

    Object.keys(ins).forEach(key => {
        updates['/rooms/' + roomPushKey + '/ins/' + key] = true;
    });

    return admin.database().ref().update(updates);

}).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
    //+ other rerror treatment if necessary

});
```

In other words, instead of replacing the full `ins` object, you add new children nodes in the existing ins node.

Comment: Thanks again Renaud but this, instead of cloning the full list of "key: pair"'s in "Ins", is replacing the "Rooms/{pushId}/Ins" for the last key in the forEach loop...  I get, for instance: `Ins: { 2525104157711 }`

Comment: Try this: 

`Object.keys(ins).forEach(key => {
        updates['/rooms/' + roomPushKey + '/ins/' + key] = true;
    });
`

Comment: @JoaoAlvesMarrucho Alexander is right, there was a mistake in my answer. Thanks Alexander for spotting it. I will update the answer but you don't have to accept it, of course!

Comment: You guys solved the problem and the answer is perfectly correct. So of course I will accept the answer. Thank you both. :-)

Comment: @RenaudTarnec and Alexander using this code, would you know a way to check if the new node "Key" already exists on the database (and if so do something – like add and extra character at the end of the string)? I will create a question for that and will share the link here soon. Would really appreciate your help.

Comment: @JoaoAlvesMarrucho With regards to your data model, you will have to query the existing ins and loop over the object to detect if it exists

Comment: Banging my head against the table here...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50156736/how-to-query-the-existing-children-and-loop-over-an-object-to-detect-if-it-exist 
Help!

Comment: @JoaoAlvesMarrucho I've worked out an answer, see there. Hope it helps.