# How to query the existing children and loop over an Object to detect if it exists in Firebase using a Google Cloud Function?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, foreach, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to update (adding) some children on a firebase database. On this scenario I need to update a node without overwriting all the child nodes with Google Cloud Function using an update Object.

> This question derives from this one here: [How to update a node without overwriting all the child nodes with Google Cloud Function using a update Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50139303/how-to-update-a-node-without-overwriting-all-the-child-nodes-with-google-cloud-f/50139441?noredirect=1#comment87326770_50139441)

My data structure is like this:

```
root: { 
  doors: {
    111111111111: {
       MACaddress: "111111111111",
       inRoom: "-LBMH_8KHf_N9CvLqhzU", // I will need this value for the clone's path
       ins: {
          // I am creating several "key: pair"s here, something like:
          1525104151100: true,
          1525104151183: true,
       }
    },
    222222222222: {
       MACaddress: "222222222222",
       inRoom: "-LBMH_8KHf_N9CvLqhzU", // I will need this value for the clone's path
       ins: {
          // I am creating several "key: pair"s here, something like:
          2525104157710: true,
          2525104157711: true,
       }
    }
  },
  rooms: {
    -LBMH_8KHf_N9CvLqhzU: {
      ins: {
        // I want the function to clone the same data here:
        1525104151100: true,
        1525104151183: true,
      }
    }
  }
```

I am trying to to query the existing "ins" and loop over the object to detect if it exists before I add them so I can add a suffix to the key in case they are already there. This is my function ate the moment.

```
 exports.updateBuildingsOuts = functions.database.ref('/doors/{MACaddress}').onWrite((change, context) => {
    const afterData = change.after.val(); // data after the write

    const roomPushKey = afterData.inRoom;
    const ins = afterData.ins;

    const updates = {};
    // forEach loop to update the keys individually
    Object.keys(ins).forEach(key => {
            parentPath =  ['/rooms/' + roomPushKey + '/ins/']; // defining the path where I want to check if the data exists
            // querying the "ins"
            admin.database().ref().parentPath.on('value', function(snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasChild(key)) {
                    updates['/rooms/' + roomPushKey + '/ins/' + key + "_a"] = true; // define 'updates' Object adding a suffix "_a"

                    return admin.database().ref().update(updates); // do the update adding the suffix "_a"

                } else {
                    updates['/rooms/' + roomPushKey + '/ins/' + key] = true; // define update Object without suffix

                    return admin.database().ref().update(updates); // do the 'updates' without suffix
                }
              });
        });
```

This cloud function is retrieving an Error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
>       at Object.keys.forEach.key

I am sure I overcomplicating but I haven't been able to find a cleaner logic for this.

Would you have any suggestions on how to do this leanly? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do as follow:

```
let afterIns;
exports.updateRoom = functions.database.ref('/doors/{MACaddress}').onWrite((change, context) => {

    const beforeData = change.before.val();  //data before
    const insBefore = beforeData.ins;

    const afterData = change.after.val(); // data after the write
    const roomPushKey = afterData.inRoom;
    afterIns = afterData.ins;

    return admin.database().ref().update(updates);

    const updates = {};

    Object.keys(ins).forEach(key => {
        if (insBefore.hasOwnProperty(key)) { // checking if the insBefore object has a key equal to value 'key'
            //True -> add an extra character at the existing key
            updates['/rooms/' + roomPushKey + '/ins/' + key + '_a'] = true;  //<- _a being the extra character
        } else {
            updates['/rooms/' + roomPushKey + '/ins/' + key] = true;
        }
    });

    return admin.database().ref().update(updates);

}).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
    //+ other error treatment if necessary

});
```

Don't forget the function returns the data before `change.before.val();` (in addition to the data after), therefore you don't have to do `admin.database().ref().parentPath.on('value', function(snapshot) {`

---

EDIT after comments

This should work, but I haven't test it. You may need to test is `insBefore` is undefined in addition to testing it is null.  I let you fine tune it.

```
let insAfter;
let roomPushKey ;
exports.updateRoomIns = functions.database.ref('/doors/{MACaddress}').onWrite((change, context) => {
    const afterData = change.after.val(); // data after the write
    roomPushKey = afterData.inRoom;
    insAfter = afterData.ins;
    return admin.database().ref('/rooms/' + roomPushKey).once('value').then(snapshot => {
    const insBefore = snapshot.val().ins;
    const updates = {};
    if (insBefore === null || insBefore === undefined ) {
        Object.keys(insAfter).forEach(key => {
           updates['/rooms/' + roomPushKey + '/ins/' + key] = true;
        });
    } else {
        Object.keys(insAfter).forEach(key => {
           if (insBefore.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
              updates['/rooms/' + roomPushKey + '/ins/' + key + '_a'] = true; 
           } else {
              updates['/rooms/' + roomPushKey + '/ins/' + key] = true;
           }
        });
    }
    return admin.database().ref().update(updates);
    });
});.catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
    //+ other error treatment if necessary

});
```

Comment: Thanks Renaud. but this function doesn't like it if there is no "Ins" yet on the "Rooms" node: 
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined
    at Object.keys.forEach.key`.

It's also looping through all the existing data on the original "Doors" node, comparing it to the new data, and if it finds that the new key was already there, it adds a suffix and, clones all of those `keys: value_a` in the Rooms node...

Comment: Is it possible to loop through the children on "ins" existing in the "Rooms" node and only add a suffix if that specific _in_ was  already there.

Comment: @JoaoAlvesMarrucho I would suggest you ask another question. Also  you may accept and upvote this answer if it satisfies your original question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: oooooooookkkkkk :)

Comment: @JoaoAlvesMarrucho Actually I didn't see that you were having an error `TypeError...` You should test if insBefore is not null.

Comment: @JoaoAlvesMarrucho I'v edited my answer to lookup in the `rooms` node.

Comment: I have posed a new question as a follow up if you have the time @Renaud : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50234563/how-to-query-the-existing-children-of-a-sibling-node-and-loop-over-them-to-detec